# Spring MongoDB - write a query with multiple $or conditions

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongodb

For an assignment I have to write a query with multiple OR conditions.

If I had to write it using MongoDB Query Language it would be trivial

```
{ $and : [ 
  { $or : [ { "field1" : "value1" }, { "field2" : "value2" } ] }, 
  { $or : [ { "field3" : "value3" }, { "field3" : null }, { "field3" : { $exists : true }} ] } 
] }
```

**I there a way to achieve this using Spring MongoDB ?**

I tried

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(
  Criteria.where("field1").is("value1"),
  Criteria.where("field2").is("value2"),
));
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(
  Criteria.where("field3").is("value3"),
  Criteria.where("field3").is(null),
  Criteria.where("field3").exists(false),
));
```

and also tried

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(
  Criteria.where("field3").is("value3")
  .orOperator(Criteria.where("field3").is(null))
  .orOperator(Criteria.where("field3").exists(false))
  .andOperator(
     Criteria.where("field1").is("value1")
     .orOperator(Criteria.where("field2").is("value2"))
);
```

I get the following message when trying to execute either queries.

> Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you can't add a
> second '$or' expression specified as [...]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know spring very well, but I suspect you need to add an `andOperator`? Something like `query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(new Criteria().orOperator(...), new Criteria().orOperator(...)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this piece of code:

```java
Criteria firstOrCriteria = new Criteria().orOperator(
    Criteria.where("field1").is("value1"),
    Criteria.where("field2").is("value2"));

Criteria secondOrCriteria = new Criteria().orOperator(
    Criteria.where("field3").is("value3"),
    Criteria.where("field3").is(null),
    Criteria.where("field3").exists(true));

Criteria andCriteria = new Criteria().andOperator(firstOrCriteria, secondOrCriteria);

Query query = new Query(andCriteria);
```